# Learning asyncio: Run a function with a delay asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have been trying to learn asyncio for a few days now and I cannot get this example function to work. I want to speed up making a few hundred HTTP requests but I want to start simple. I would like to be able to specify how many requests I want. I have been getting a lot of different errors as I have been tweaking things but I can't get it working.

Here is my code:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def say():
  print("Started")
  await time.sleep(3) #something that takes a long time like an http request
  print("Finsihed")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.gather(say(),say(),say())
loop.run_forever()
```

I am very ned to this and I am sure I am doing something wrong with running the loop but I don't know what to try next. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What error(s) are you getting? The first step from what you've provided is to do something with `gather`'s result, such as `asyncio.run(asyncio.gather(...))` (then you wouldn't even need `loop`).

Comment: It;s not printing In the order I wanted. I want it to print: Started Started Started Finished Finished Finished but instead it prints started finished started finished... I am getting errors about await being connected to an expression and all kinds of things... My current error is: ```File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 37, in run
    raise ValueError("a coroutine was expected, got {!r}".format(main))
ValueError: a coroutine was expected, got <_GatheringFuture pending>```

Comment: Change `await time.sleep(3)` to `await asyncio.sleep(3)` and you should see the output you expect.

Comment: @dirn I have seen that in examples... but It doesn't seem to work with other things... I understand there is a built-in sleep command, but time.sleep is just a filler for something that takes a long time (like an HTTP request). Why doesn't it work with time.sleep?

Comment: You can't await arbitrary things.

Comment: I have seen examples of code (that are more complicated and I don't understand) that will print out the HTML for 10 different websites instantly (It usually takes like 10 seconds) using this library. Using await for when the response is getting back. How is that possible if I cannot use anything arbitrary? Here is some code I found online that works but I cannot understand why: https://stackabuse.com/python-async-await-tutorial/

Comment: You can only await things that are awaitable. Examples of that are things that are defined with `async def`, tasks, and futures. The examples on that page all so that. If you want to make HTTP requests, you can use aiohttp like the author of that post does.

Comment: @dirn Sadly `asyncio.run(asyncio.gather(...))` doesn't work because `asyncio.run()` for some reason only accepts coroutine objects.

Comment: @user4815162342 TIL. Thanks

Comment: @dirn Does the python package "requests" work or just "aiohttp"?

Comment: Requests isn't asyncio-aware. I think aiohttp is the most common. HTTPX should also work.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

- You can't use `time.sleep()` in asyncio code because calling a blocking function like `time.sleep()` blocks the whole event loop.
- You can't just invoke `asyncio.gather()`, you must await it.
- You should probably use the newer and more robust `asyncio.run()` API rather than the older `loop.run_forever()`

Here is the code with those issues fixed:

```
import asyncio

async def say():
    print("Started")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("Finsihed")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(say(), say(), say())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Also note that you will need to use an asyncio-aware library like like [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) to make proper use of asyncio.

Comment: Thank You so much! I got it working. I ended up using requests_async but same idea I think. I really appreciate your thorough response, but I have one more question. If I wanted to run say() x times, how can I create a way of adding say() to gather x time? To rephrase, how can I programmatically define how many times I want it to run then it is added to the gather function that many times, and thus, asynchronously run that many times?